# docker compose volumes empty folder

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

inside my vvchatbot folder are

- app
- configs
- docker-compose.yaml

docker compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./app
      args:
        - LLAMA_2_ACCESS=${LLAMA_2_ACCESS}
        - CHAT_MODEL=${CHAT_MODEL}
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
    command: streamlit run app.py
    volumes:
      - app-configs:/app/configs  # Mount the app-configs volume
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
  ....

# Define named volumes
volumes:
  app-configs:
```

and this is example of my app Docker file

```
# Stage 1: Install Python 3.8 and essential dependencies
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04 as builder

...

FROM builder as app_builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY . .
....
```

I simplified the structure but the problem is that after i build app using `docker-compose up --build -d` inside app container i see configs folder but it's empty

Comment: You're mounting a Docker named volume over the `configs` directory; what do you expect puts content into that volume?

Comment: @DavidMaze that my app container will have acsess to files inside configs folder

Comment: Are you looking for a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), which will inject host-filesystem content directly into the container, instead of a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), which manages persistent storage inside of Docker?